# Do I need Cataclysm attached to my account in order to train Archaeology?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

With the new expansion out, do I need to have Cataclysm added to my account in order to go to an Archaeology trainer and start learning/using the new secondary skill?

Comment: The way this is presented in-game is somewhat mystifying if you don't have Cataclysm. I was confused when talking to the Archeology trainer in Ironforge just opened a blank dialog window.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Cataclysm is required to train archaeology. The trainers will have nothing to teach you if your account does not have Cataclysm enabled.
[image]

Comment: This has already been said in my answer. What do you post that's new in this answer?

Comment: @Brian 1) I had this question open in a new tab before your answer went up, sorry about that. 2) You erm... kind of got the question backwards with respect to the Yes/No aspect.

Comment: Yes I clearify that what I meant by no. However, if the answer was fully read then one we have receive the same and correct answer from my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response guys, you both covered it nicely

Comment: I have added a picture to the accepted answer demonstrating the truth of it.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is **no** *you can not train without upgrading*. One can **only** train Archaeology after one's account has been updated to Cataclyms. There isn't an screenshot that can be used as proof. However, proof can be found on [**page**](http://www.wowhead.com/skill=794/archaeology) from the trustworthy fellows at WoW Head.

Comment: This *is* in fact correct, though he inverted the question from "Do I need Cataclysm to learn archaeology?" to "Can I learn archaeology without Cataclysm", which is probably why the downvotes are coming.